# How to arbitrarily put a name in the bracket { } of Thebibliography Environment?

Tags: bibliographies

When using Thebibliography Environment we have to type {} before any reference, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
...
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem {} D. Hilbert, The concept of Groups, ...
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that if I wish to put, say H89 in {}, the output still shows the number indicating the order of the paper. So in such a case, how do I arbitrarily put what I wish to put in {}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write

```
\bibitem[Hil89]{H89} D. Hilbert, The concept of Groups, ...
```

The material in curly braces is the "citation key" -- use it in commands such as

```
\cite{H89}
```

In contrast, the material in square brackets, which is optional, is what will be shown as the *output* of the preceding citation command. If no optional argument is provided, the default, i.e., numeric output is produced.

Here's what is produced by an edited version of your example code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
As shown in \cite{H89}, \dots
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Hil89]{H89} D. Hilbert, The Concept of Groups, \dots
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```